# Limitar el número máximo de bases de datos de un usuario en postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Buenas, he estado buscando información sobre el tema y no he encontrado nada al respecto.

Seguro que aquí alguien puede asegurarme que no es posible limitar el número de bases de datos que puede crear un rol en postgresql. O si existe alguna forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Te refieres a bases de datos que podría crear un usuario o cantidad que se le pueden asignar?

Comment: a la cantidad que podría crear un usuario.

Comment: Me atrevo a decir que no existe ese tipo de restricciones, en mtbd como mysql si eh visto que se pueden limitar recursos pero en postgresql no eh visto algo al menos similar a lo que comentas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez que le concedes a un rol el privilegio de poder crear bases de datos, **no hay forma de limitar cuantos puede crear.**

Lo más cercano a lo que pides se lograría no concediéndole el privilegio de crear bases de datos a este rol en particular, sino más bien usando un *superuser* para crear la base de datos en nombre de este rol cuando sea necesario. O sea que, aunque el rol no puede crear la base de datos por sí mismo, esto no impide que llegue a ser dueño de una base de datos si el *superuser* crea la base de datos en su nombre.

El crear una base de datos asignando a otro rol como dueño se puede lograr de esta forma:

```
CREATE DATABASE base_de_datos OWNER rol; -- el dueño de la base de datos es rol
```

...o también de esta forma:

```
createdb -O rol base_de_datos
```

Referencia: [22.2. Creating a Database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/manage-ag-createdb.html).

Comment: Perfecto, eso me sirve, muchas gracias a todos.